# Unable To Link An External JavaScript File In Pug Using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I want to use ChartJS so I can display charts on my website, but I don't want the JavaScript to be separate from the html. I am using pug (jade) as my view engine which I know is working properly.

First I linked ChartJS in my index.pug file and created my canvas:

```
html
head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/styles.css', type='text/css')
    script(type="text/javascript", src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js')
    script(type="text/javascript", src='/javascripts/chart.js')
    title= title
body
    h1= message
    canvas#myChart(width='400', height='400')
```

Next, In my chart.js file I did:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

For some reason, the chart isn't being displayed, however if I use script tags and put the JavaScript directly in the pug file it works fine. I know that the JavaScript file is being linked correctly because I checked it using an alert. Any ideas on why my chart isn't being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code inside the document ready like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your chart code goes here.
});
```